# How to use options parameter from rasterizeHtml.js?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, html-rendering, rasterizing, html-renderer

I tried this logic but it didn't work:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 document.body.appendChild(rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(document.body.innerHTML, canvas, {height:'1000px'}));
```

Options is an object and I tried to pass in it the width and height, but it is not working.
The script that I'm using for this library is from cloud flare:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rasterizehtml/1.2.2/rasterizeHTML.allinone.js"></script>
```

I did it some how but I don't understand why the canvas is not displaying correctly.

```
 const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 canvas.style.width = "100%";
 canvas.style.height = "600px";
 html = document.querySelector('#main').innerHTML;
 document.body.appendChild(
  rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(html).then(function (renderResult) {
    context.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
    context.drawImage(renderResult.image, 0, 0, 1600, 800);
     })
  );
```

I tried to put the content of the entire web page in canvas(below under the box with the green border) but it looks like this:
[image: canvas]